# What is the way to declare a generic T varibale inside Exception subclass?

Tags: java, generics, exception, subclass

Well, there is a subclass of `NumberFormatException` with additional varibales and constructors. But it is not possible to store generic variables inside it. I'm going to store the `T element` variable (that is set from the inside as constructos's argument) inside my new class.

Consider the code:

```
public class NumberFormatException<T> extends java.lang.NumberFormatException implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 586367686351473424L;
    private Throwable cause;
    private T el;

    public <T> NumberFormatException(T element, java.lang.NumberFormatException e)
    {   super();
        cause = e.getCause();
        el = element;
        Report.NumberFormatException(element);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();                   
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);                   
        cause.printStackTrace(pw);                              
        String stacktrace = sw.toString();                      
        Report.msg(stacktrace, level.high);                     
    }
}
```

Error: `The generic class NumberFormatException may not subclass java.lang.Throwable`

Any comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR: You can't, it would break try/catch.**

The problem is with type erasure.   Exception catching uses run-time type information, which is missing the generic information.  This means that: `catch (MyGenericException<String> e)` would catch any MyGenericException, regardless of the actual type thrown.

Since this is the case, the language designers decided that subclasses of `Throwable` aren't safe to be generic, because it wouldn't ever work as expected in a catch block.

Comment: I just don't get it: why should I declare the method as generic too if I only have an argument inside and don't return or throw any generic stuff

Comment: What method? You created the class `NumberFormatException<T>`, which is the problem.  If you don't make that *class* generic, you'll be able to get it to compile.

Comment: but if I have a generic variable inside this class I should create `NumberFormatException<T>` class

Comment: is Object type for field OK ?

Comment: Depends on what you need.  You lose the static type information if you use "Object", but depending on what you do with that object field, that may not matter.  Especially if you only use it's "toString" method.

Comment: Right, .toString() is enough